# In Angular site, element not able to locate error displaying even xpath is correct. tried with javascript executer still its not working

Tags: java, selenium, automation

It's not in frame and throwing an error while enter credit card number. Please note it's an angular-based website.

```java
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//input[@id='credit-card-number']")
).sendKeys("4111111111111111");
```

---

Error in console

```
FAILED: orderplace
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='credit-card-number']"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

Comment: Be sure page is loaded and element is realy present. Start with Thread.sleep(int miliseconds), consider implicit or explicit wait methods, see https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html. If it not helps please add html source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement myinput = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='credit-card-number']")));
myinput.sendKeys("4111111111111111");
```

I have added `wait` 'till the input box is visible. Once it is visible you can put text inside it.

Comment: Still its not working. focus already in the textbox but not adding text in textbox.

Comment: Is it showing any error?